# Log4J Custom plugins in Bazel

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, bazel

My project uses Bazel as a build system.

I need to create a Log4J custom configuration plugin.

The problem is that Bazel doesn't seem to generate the Log4j2Plugins.dat file or include it in my jars.

I assume I need some kind of compiler plugin for this. How do I use it?

```
@Plugin(name="MyConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(200)
public class MyConfigurationFactory  extends ConfigurationFactory {
...
}
```

**Edit:**
I've managed to get the Log4J2 annotation plugin to run and I have the Log4j2Plugins.dat file. Now I need to get that file into the jar...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java_plugin`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_plugin) to run custom annotation processors.

To include the resulting files, I think you just need to depend on the `java_plugin` from the `java_binary` or `java_library` whose jar you want to include them in.

Answer (score 0):

This link gives useful information, about the process of registering a `java` plugin and having it work with the bazel compilation [here](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/ZRWdqJfYEPw/m/4pYq884kIQAJ).
This link describes about including a lombok annotation processor, but you can adapt it for Log4j.